# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_objdetect

Tags: java, android, opencv, javacv

I'm trying to use javacv library in my project . I have imported javacpp.jar and javacv.jar in my libs folder . But when I try to load haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml from raw folder into CvHaarClassifierCascade according to following code

```
 CvHaarClassifierCascade cascade = new CvHaarClassifierCascade(cvLoad("android.resource:// com.era.facerecognitionandcropping/raw/haarcascade_frontalface_alt"));
```

The following exception is thrown .

```
06-12 16:09:08.550: E/AndroidRuntime(24730): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-12 16:09:08.550: E/AndroidRuntime(24730): Process: com.era.facerecognitionandcropping, PID: 24730
06-12 16:09:08.550: E/AndroidRuntime(24730): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_objdetect
06-12 16:09:08.550: E/AndroidRuntime(24730):    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:336)
06-12 16:09:08.550: E/AndroidRuntime(24730):    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:315)
06-12 16:09:08.550: E/AndroidRuntime(24730):    at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_objdetect$CvHaarClassifierCascade.<clinit>(opencv_objdetect.java:176)
06-12 16:09:08.550: E/AndroidRuntime(24730):    at com.era.facerecognitionandcropping.MainActivity$4.onClick(MainActivity.java:271)
06-12 16:09:08.550: E/AndroidRuntime(24730):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4471)
06-12 16:09:08.550: E/AndroidRuntime(24730):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18784)
06-12 16:09:08.550: E/AndroidRuntime(24730):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
06-12 16:09:08.550: E/AndroidRuntime(24730):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
06-12 16:09:08.550: E/AndroidRuntime(24730):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
06-12 16:09:08.550: E/AndroidRuntime(24730):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5330)
06-12 16:09:08.550: E/AndroidRuntime(24730):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-12 16:09:08.550: E/AndroidRuntime(24730):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-12 16:09:08.550: E/AndroidRuntime(24730):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:828)
06-12 16:09:08.550: E/AndroidRuntime(24730):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:644)
06-12 16:09:08.550: E/AndroidRuntime(24730):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-12 16:09:08.550: E/AndroidRuntime(24730): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_objdetect
06-12 16:09:08.550: E/AndroidRuntime(24730):    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
06-12 16:09:08.550: E/AndroidRuntime(24730):    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:251)
06-12 16:09:08.550: E/AndroidRuntime(24730):    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:334)
06-12 16:09:08.550: E/AndroidRuntime(24730):    ... 14 more
06-12 16:09:08.550: E/AndroidRuntime(24730): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_features2d
06-12 16:09:08.550: E/AndroidRuntime(24730):    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:336)
06-12 16:09:08.550: E/AndroidRuntime(24730):    at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_objdetect.<clinit>(opencv_objdetect.java:97)
06-12 16:09:08.550: E/AndroidRuntime(24730):    ... 17 more
06-12 16:09:08.550: E/AndroidRuntime(24730): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_features2d
06-12 16:09:08.550: E/AndroidRuntime(24730):    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
06-12 16:09:08.550: E/AndroidRuntime(24730):    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:251)
06-12 16:09:08.550: E/AndroidRuntime(24730):    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:334)
06-12 16:09:08.550: E/AndroidRuntime(24730):    ... 18 more
06-12 16:09:08.550: E/AndroidRuntime(24730): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui
06-12 16:09:08.550: E/AndroidRuntime(24730):    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:336)
06-12 16:09:08.550: E/AndroidRuntime(24730):    at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_features2d.<clinit>(opencv_features2d.java:93)
06-12 16:09:08.550: E/AndroidRuntime(24730):    ... 21 more
06-12 16:09:08.550: E/AndroidRuntime(24730): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui
06-12 16:09:08.550: E/AndroidRuntime(24730):    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
06-12 16:09:08.550: E/AndroidRuntime(24730):    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:251)
06-12 16:09:08.550: E/AndroidRuntime(24730):    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:334)
06-12 16:09:08.550: E/AndroidRuntime(24730):    ... 22 more
06-12 16:09:08.550: E/AndroidRuntime(24730): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc
06-12 16:09:08.550: E/AndroidRuntime(24730):    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:336)
06-12 16:09:08.550: E/AndroidRuntime(24730):    at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui.<clinit>(opencv_highgui.java:91)
06-12 16:09:08.550: E/AndroidRuntime(24730):    ... 25 more
06-12 16:09:08.550: E/AndroidRuntime(24730): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc
06-12 16:09:08.550: E/AndroidRuntime(24730):    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
06-12 16:09:08.550: E/AndroidRuntime(24730):    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:251)
06-12 16:09:08.550: E/AndroidRuntime(24730):    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:334)
06-12 16:09:08.550: E/AndroidRuntime(24730):    ... 26 more
06-12 16:09:08.550: E/AndroidRuntime(24730): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core
06-12 16:09:08.550: E/AndroidRuntime(24730):    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:336)
06-12 16:09:08.550: E/AndroidRuntime(24730):    at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc.<clinit>(opencv_imgproc.java:96)
06-12 16:09:08.550: E/AndroidRuntime(24730):    ... 29 more
06-12 16:09:08.550: E/AndroidRuntime(24730): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core
06-12 16:09:08.550: E/AndroidRuntime(24730):    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
06-12 16:09:08.550: E/AndroidRuntime(24730):    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:251)
06-12 16:09:08.550: E/AndroidRuntime(24730):    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:334)
06-12 16:09:08.550: E/AndroidRuntime(24730):    ... 30 more
06-12 16:09:08.550: E/AndroidRuntime(24730): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load jniopencv_core from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/mnt/asec/com.era.facerecognitionandcropping-2/pkg.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/mnt/asec/com.era.facerecognitionandcropping-2/lib, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null
06-12 16:09:08.550: E/AndroidRuntime(24730):    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
06-12 16:09:08.550: E/AndroidRuntime(24730):    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:606)
06-12 16:09:08.550: E/AndroidRuntime(24730):    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:444)
06-12 16:09:08.550: E/AndroidRuntime(24730):    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:368)
06-12 16:09:08.550: E/AndroidRuntime(24730):    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:315)
06-12 16:09:08.550: E/AndroidRuntime(24730):    at com.googlecode.jav
```

How can I solve this error ? Any advice is of great help .

Comment: Could you please share the content of your build.gradle  where you have added these two JARs ?

Comment: I am developing in eclipse

Comment: Do you use version 0.6 of java_CV? Please also add your gradle file.

Comment: I dont know the version of javacv . I am developing in eclipse

Comment: I forgot that this IDE exists for Android development. Please also list the names of your jar files. If you don't know it download the latest jars. Might be something regarding outdated references.